# MVC controller ignoring security.php

Tags: php, authentication, security, session

I have security.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged']) || !$_SESSION['logged'] ) {
    header("location:/backoffice/login.php");
    session_destroy();
}
```

And my controller usersControll.php:

```
<?php
include "security.php";
include "users.php"; //model 

$option = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'option', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

switch ($option) {
    cases...
    case 9:
        $user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'user', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $passwd = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'passwd', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        logInLogOut::logIn($user, $passwd);
        break;
    case 10:
        logInLogOut::logOut();
        break;
    More cases...
}
```

The problem is when I log in, it enters inside the switch (controller) ignoring security.php. It shouldn't go in because $_SESSION['logged'] isn't set. I send the logIn data to the controller from a form and it send the switch option (9) through the form too with a hidden input.

I expect to not enter in the switch and it enters in all time, i tried switching session values and conditions but didnt work

Comment: `header()` just sends a response header to the browser, suggesting that it redirects to another page once it's finished receiving the current response. It doesn't stop the rest of your PHP script from executing, if that's what you were expecting. You need to to `exit();` after that command in order to stop the rest of the code from running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your security.php and exit the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged']) || !$_SESSION['logged'] ) {
    header("location:/backoffice/login.php");
    session_destroy();
    exit();
}
```